How to re-tag git repository and submodules
I am in the process of moving git repositories from Azure DevOps to GitHub.
The plan is to git clone mirror from Azure, redirect the URL to GitHub, and push onto there. No problem so far.
One repo used as a submodule in many other repos sadly has had one huge file (~250M) added without lfs configured. This make GitHub reject the push.
I know how to remove this file and rewrite history, but that would break the historic references between the referencing repos and the submodule.
Before I move out of Azure, can I travel through commits of this submodule on all referencing repos and apply an identical tag on the referencing repos and the submodule repo?
I am looking for some way to script/automate this, as it is a lot of commits I am facing.
Other ways to achieve the same goal (moving to GitHub with intact history) are very welcome.

I figured out a solution myself. I would like to post it here, but I used ChatGPT to sanitize a few details so it is banned on SO :-(

as long as you wrote it yourself, I think it's okay if you consulted Chat GPT.  Just write it in your own words.

I have built this solution which add 'synchronization tags' on both parent and sub repositories:
$mainrepo = "repo-name"
$subrepo = "subrepo-name"
$subPath = "path-to-submodule"
$baseTag = "$mainrepo/$subrepo"
# Get the list of commits from git rev-list
$commits = git rev-list HEAD --oneline $subPath

# Reverse the order of commits correctly
$reversedCommits = @($commits)
[Array]::Reverse($reversedCommits)

$counter = 0
# Iterate over each commit entry
foreach ($commit in $reversedCommits) {
    # Split by the first space
    $splitText = $commit -split ' ', 2
    # The first part is the commit SHA
    $commitSha = $splitText[0]
    
    $counter += 1
    $tag = "$baseTag/$counter"
    # Output the commit SHA and counter
    Write-Output "$commitSha $tag $($splitText[1])"

    git checkout $commitSha

    # Check if the tag already exists in the main repository
    if (-not (git tag --list $tag)) {
        git tag $tag
    } else {
        Write-Output "Tag $tag already exists in main repository, skipping."
    }

    git submodule update $subPath
    Push-Location $subPath

    # Check if the tag already exists in the submodule
    if (-not (git tag --list $tag)) {
        git tag $tag
    } else {
        Write-Output "Tag $tag already exists in submodule, skipping."
    }

    Pop-Location
}

